# How to replace MPI_Pack_size if I need to send more than 2GB of data?

Tags: mpi, buffer-overflow

I want to send and receive more than 2 GB of data using MPI and I came across a lot of articles like the ones cited below:
http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/can-we-count-on-mpi-to-handle-large-datasets, 
http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/new-things-in-mpi-3-mpi_count
talking about changes that are made starting with MPI 3.0 allowing to send and receive bigger chunks of data.

Most of the functions now are receiving as parameter an MPI_Count object instead of int, but not all of them.

How can I replace

```
int MPI_Pack_size(int incount, MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Comm comm,
    int *size)
```

in order to get the size of a larger buffer? (because here the size can only be at most 2GB)

Comment: Do you really need MPI_Pack_size? Can't you use derived types of larger size?

Comment: Why do you need pack for >2GB? That's strictly in the bandwidth-limited regime so packing should be of no value whatsoever.

Comment: @Vladimir F Let' assume I really need more than 2GB, if I use derived types of larger size it's not helpful because the size parameter from MPI_Pack_size returns the number of bytes..

Comment: But why you need the pack at all? See Jeff's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The MPI_Pack routines (MPI_Pack, MPI_Unpack, MPI_Pack_size, MPI_Pack_external) are, as you see, unable to support more than 32 bits worth of data, due to the integer pointer used as a return value.  I don't know why the standard did not provide MPI_Pack_x, MPI_Unpack_x, MPI_Pack_size_x, and MPI_Pack_external_x -- presumably an oversight?  As Jeff suggests, it might have been done so because packing multiple gigs of data is unlikely to provide much benefit.  Still, it breaks orthogonality not to have those...

A quality implementation (I do not know if MPICH is one of those) should return an error about the type being too big, allowing you to pack a smaller amount of data.